# How to set the current tab/content on page postback

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following JSFiddle which changes the tab/content based on user selection: http://jsfiddle.net/sikni8/3d64w6gf/1/

HTML snippet sample:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRegister" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Register" OnClick="btnRegister_Click" />
<!--<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Register" runat="server" />-->
```

The `btnRegister` button perform some action when clicked. When the page does a postback, how can I ensure the tab/content which was there is displayed.

For example, if I click on the `Register` button the page refreshes and brings the first tab/content to view. I would like to change it so that when `Register` button is clicked and the page reloads, it should remain with the same tab/content.

I can use `sessionStorage` but I would like to request some assistance.

Tried this but didn't work:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function (e) {
            localStorage.setItem("whichTab", $("#tabs nav ul li.tab-current"));
            alert(localStorage.getItem("whichTab"));
        });
    </script>
```

I am using cbpFWTabs.js file to achieve the tab class switch which is in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar by using hidden field, where I stored the id/class of the current tab in hidden field and after postback I just displayed the current tab again.

Comment: Are you willing to share how you accomplished it? Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer. You must comment rather than answering like this.

Comment: It was very simple, I was uploading files from multiple tabs, and on upload button I was saving the class of the current tab and after uploading the file I just called the function of setTab(); which set the current tab again.
by the way you just want to select current tab again right? not save the content of the tab?

@Rohit Arora, since I am new here I cant add comment yet. Please do not downvote the answer.

Comment: @ShazebAli Ok Please edit your answer once so i can revert my downvote. Other wise i cannot do that.Thanks.